# MaterialButton style shapeAppearance not working

Tags: material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I'm struggling to set the right style for my button in the project. I don't know why `shapeAppearance` not working. Even if I use only `cornerSize` it's not working.

I have a base style for a button:

```
<style name="SnButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/MyShapeAppearance</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@null</item>
</style>
```

This is my shape appearance for a button:

```
<style name="MyShapeAppearance" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">2dp</item>
</style>
```

This is my base theme: `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge`

What should I do to force `shapeAppearance` work in my case? Or at least `cornerSize`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out why style was not working!

The problem was in the way I set the color for the button. I've used `android:background`, but `backgroundTint` must be used.

Comment: Using `android:background` the `MaterialButton` doesn't use its own `MaterialShapeDrawable` for the background. This means that features like shape appearance, stroke and rounded corners are ignored.